# Accessing Configuration Settings in a static context

Tags: c#, asp.net

It is possible to access the configuration settings value in a static context?

For instance, here is the code, which fails with a red line stating that one "cannot access non-static property 'Settings' in static context."  All I need is the value of the setting.

```
namespace MyCompany.Sample.EmailConnector.Provider.Implementation
{
    class GmailEmailConnectorProvider : EmailConnectorProvider
    {
        private string clientSecret = Settings.ClientSecret; // Here is the error
                                         ^^

        public override Email SendTestEmail(string address, string message)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access properties of an object in field initializers like that. You need to move the initialization to a constructor

```
class GmailEmailConnectorProvider : EmailConnectorProvider
{
    private string clientSecret;

    public GmailEmailConnectorProvider()
    {
        clientSecret = Settings.ClientSecret;
    }
}
```

Also, it's generally not a good idea to do this (access the property from a constructor) if `Settings` is virtual, unless you seal `GmailEmailConnectorProvider` or you are otherwise certain that nothing will ever inherit from it.

Comment: Ok, awesome. I will just seal it; programatically its designed to be an abstraction endpoint.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `Default` static property:

```
private string clientSecret = Settings.Default.ClientSecret;
```